# How do you use two setIntervals with different timers in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

So right now I have a `verifyScreen` which users are sent to when they don't have a verified email. I have a `setInterval` function that runs every 5 seconds to see if the user has confirmed their email.

I also need to have a second `setInterval` for the resend email button in case a user has not received it. It counts down by 1 until it hits 0 and the user can resend an email.

If I have one or the other in my `useEffect` everything works fine. They also won't run together if the other is running so I need some help understanding how `setInterval` works behind the scenes and how I can fix my issue. Thank you.

```
  const [emailTimer, setEmailTimer] = useState(0);
  const [, setUser] = useAtom(userAtom);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userTimer = setInterval(async () => {
      const refreshedUser = auth().currentUser;
      console.log('checked user');

      if (refreshedUser?.emailVerified) {
        clearInterval(userTimer);
        setUser(refreshedUser);
      } else {
        await auth().currentUser?.reload();
      }
    }, 5000);

    const resendEmailTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (emailTimer <= 0) {
        clearInterval(resendEmailTimer);
      } else {
        console.log('second subtracted');
        setEmailTimer(emailTimer - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(userTimer);
      clearInterval(resendEmailTimer);
    };
  }, [emailTimer]);
```

If you know the solution and can also explain to me the `why` behind all this, I would really appreciate that.

Edit, my component which sets the email timer:

```
   <View style={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}>
     <PrimaryButton
       disabled={emailTimer > 0}
       onPress={async () => {
         setEmailTimer(60);
         await handleSendEmailConfirmation();
       }}>
       <CustomText
         text={emailTimer > 0 ? `${emailTimer}` : 'Resend email'}
         color={theme.colors.white}
       />
     </PrimaryButton>
   </View>
   <OutlinedButton
     onPress={async () => {
       await handleLogOut();
     }}>
     <CustomText text="Cancel" />
   </OutlinedButton>
  </View>
```

Edit:

What happens with the code right now:

The component renders, and the user interval runs every ~5 seconds.
I click on the resend email button, which triggers the email timer every 1 second.
While the email counter is going, the user counter pauses until it hits 0.
Then the user counter resumes.

Console logs for more description:

[image]

Edit 2: Ok I managed to get both intervals working at the same time by moving the user interval outside of the useEffect. This way the email interval triggers when the state updates and it's added to the dependency array.

The one problem is the user interval that is outside of the useEffect sometimes triggers twice in the console. Not sure if that's because I'm running on a simulator or an error.

```
  const [emailTimer, setEmailTimer] = useState(0);
  const [, setUser] = useAtom(userAtom);

  const userTimer = setInterval(async () => {
    const refreshedUser = auth().currentUser;
    console.log('checked user');

    if (refreshedUser?.emailVerified) {
      clearInterval(userTimer);
      setUser(refreshedUser);
    } else {
      await auth().currentUser?.reload();
    }
  }, 10000);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resendEmailTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (emailTimer <= 0) {
        clearInterval(resendEmailTimer);
      } else {
        console.log('second subtracted');
        setEmailTimer(emailTimer - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(userTimer);
      clearInterval(resendEmailTimer);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [emailTimer]);
```

Comment: Where do you set `emailTimer` value other than inside `resendEmailTimer`?

Comment: @technophyle The only other place it gets used is for the ```disabled``` prop on the button and the text for the button shows the value of time left instead of ```Resend email```

Edit: When a user clicks on the ```Resend email``` button, I set the email state to 120 and the intervals start.

Comment: So you're saying it's always 0 or lower? No place else that sets the value to a positive number?

Comment: @technophyle I just edited my answer to you, I see what you were asking now. It gets set when the email is resent.

Comment: Did you paste all the code for `resendEmailTimer` body? Right now, it does nothing.

Comment: Try using HTML instead of that custom markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `setInterval`s, they work totally independently. Of course, if both intervals change the same variable, both will try to update the variable at the same time and sometimes, it could cause an unexpected result, but that's not your case.

One huge issue your code has is, you're creating an interval *every time* `setUser` or `emailTimer` gets updated. `setUser` will not change after the initialization but `emailTimer` gets updated frequently and thus will cause hundreds of `setInterval`s to be created. If it works correctly, that's a miracle. I'm not sure how it could work when you have one interval.

Correct approach is adding them one time when the page mounts:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const userTimer = setInterval(...);
  const resendEmailTimer = setInterval(...);
}, []); // this empty [] is the key
```

ESLint may complain about `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule but it doesn't make sense in your case, so simply suppress it. There's a lot of debate on whether this rule should be strictly enforced or not, but that's another topic.

Side note: I don't like the naming of your `emailTimer` variable. All other intervals have `xxxTimer` format, and it could easily mislead `emailTimer` is also an interval, so maybe consider renaming your state variable to `emailTimerCount`.

Comment: Thanks for that information, I'll go ahead and try this now and return to update you. But yeah if I just have the user interval, if I confirm my email from my phone the intervals stop and I get routed to the AuthStack.

Comment: Ok, updated for some more info.

Comment: Ok, so I updated my code to match yours. Removing the return and leaving the dependency array empty. Now when I click on the Resend email button, the state changes but the interval doesn't start.

Comment: Also, updated my post with console logs describing what happens with my current code.

Comment: @Vik No need to remove the return statement btw. If interval doesn't start, there's obviously a different issue.

Comment: I found that by not having the emailTimer in the dependency array the intervals will not start. By adding it, it counts down by 1000ms. If I move the user interval out of the useEffect, it works throughout the life of the component until I clear it when it hits a condition or the user logs out and I clear the timers first.